# SQL Server : backup failing error

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

Getting the below error while trying to configure the backup source and destination are in different domain.

> Executing the query "BACKUP LOG [project_management] TO  DISK = N'\\nee..." failed with the following error:
>
> "Cannot open backup device '\\qwerty.xyz.xyzinteractive.com\backup4\Teddy\TLogs\project_management_backup_2016_05_28_020039_7840447.trn'. Operating system error 1326(The user name or password is incorrect.). BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally.".
>
> Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually recommended that a backup is done local and then moved.  Here is a link that I think is related to the topic.  Are you using a service account that has appropriate privileges on both domains?

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic842263-357-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the account that's running the MSSQLSERVER service for your instance has access to the network share.

If you're running on a domain and the instance is running as the computer's SYSTEM account, then you'll want to grant access to the computer account instead of a user.

If you're not on a domain or are saving the file across domains that aren't trusted and the instance is running as the computer's SYSTEM account... well, then the easiest way to do it is to change the account to a real service account.